# Oracle - Update statement for copying dates from 1 column to another

Tags: oracle, sql-update

In my Oracle DB, there are two date columns within the CustomerActivity Table; Last Updated and Last Added. Due to several changes over the years, the application was using Last Updated, but temporarily used the Last Added Date and in some cases both the columns randomly (sounds like bad development/defect), now it's switched back to Last Updated Date (craziness right?)

In any case, I would like to copy the Last Added date values into Last Updated Date Column only if Last Added > Last Updated. After this, I'll remove the Last Added Column from the table (a permanent fix)

How can I write an Update statement for this?

Answer (score 0):

As you clearly stated, "I would like to copy the Last Added date values into Last Updated Date Column only if Last Added > Last Updated". As SQL is a declarative language, all you need to do is translate that to SQL:

> I would like to copy the Last Added date values into Last Updated Date Column

```
SET last_updated = last_added
```

> only if Last Added > Last Updated

```
WHERE last_added > last_updated
```

And now you just need to put it all together:

```
UPDATE CustomerActivity
SET    last_updated = last_added
WHERE  last_added > last_updated
```

Comment: When I run this, it results in the records being blank for the all the rows meeting the condition (before commiting), not sure why that's happening